# Logging laravel into specific channel json property

Tags: php, laravel, logging

I have a custom channel that writes logs in json formatted lines, I use this in my config/logging.php

```
<?php

use Monolog\Handler\NullHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\SyslogUdpHandler;

return [

    'channels' => [
        //...
       'events' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/events.log'),
            'level' => 'info',
            'formatter' => Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter::class,
            'formatter_with' => [
                'format' => '{"datetime":"%datetime%","level_name":"%level_name%","action":"%action%","message":"%message%"}'."\n",
                'dateFormat' => 'd-m-Y H:i:s.v'
            ],
        ]

    ]
];
```

then to write into this channel I simply use something like this:

```
<?php

Log::channel('events')->info('This is a log message');
```

the result is:

```
{"datetime":"08-05-2023 23:04:56.472","level_name":"INFO","message":"This is a log message"}
```

**I would like to write into the action property of the json in a way like this:**

```
Log::channel('events')->withAction('This is the action')->alert('This is a log message');
```

I found that I can use the withContext method in this way:

```
Log::channel('events')->withContext(['action' => 'This is the action'])->info('This is a log message');
```

But the result is unwanted, becomes something like this:

```
{"datetime":"08-05-2023 23:04:56.472","level_name":"INFO","action:{"action":"This is the action"},"message":"This is a log message"}
```

Comment: and it doesnt work using `->withContext('This is the action')`?

Comment: @N69S it gives error that must be an array, so I tried `->withContext(['This is the action'])` and output is close to the wanted one but is not ok `{"datetime":"08-05-2023 23:04:56.472","level_name":"INFO","action:["This is the action"],"message":"This is a log message"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok nevermind I found it, you pass all properties you want through the array in withContext method like this:

```
Log::channel('events')->withContext(['action' => 'This is the action', 'action2', => 'This is the second action'])->info('This is a log message');
```

Then you can access all properties values with the dot separator, in this way(similar when you are doing stuffs with eloquent and json)

```
'format' => '{"datetime":"%datetime%","level_name":"%level_name%","action":"%context.action%","action2":"%context.action2%","message":"%message%"}'."\n",
```

I really don't understand why laravel documentation is missing stuffs like that and you have to parse 1 milion classes to understand a so important behaviour